# Sorting values with a Doubly linked list

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, dll, doubly-linked-list

I'm making a WFA with some simple buttons to fill an array/list with random numbers, and trying to sort them afterwards. I just can't seem to get the sorting right. Help appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DoublyLinkedList1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Sortbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            int[] array = new int[listBox1.Items.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = int.Parse(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                }
            array = cN.notearray(array);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(array[i]);
            }
        }

        private void filllstbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            Random rd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(rd.Next(1, 9));  
            }

            }
        }

    }
```

Class cN:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DoublyLinkedList1
{
    class cN
    {
        public int V;
        public cN L;
        public cN R;
        private static cN[] n_array;
        private static cN head = null;

        public cN(cN nR, cN nL, int nV)
        {
            V = nV;
            L = nL;
            R = nR;
        }

        public static int[] notearray(int[] array)
        {
            n_array = new cN[array.Length];
            //Fill array with notes
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                n_array[i] = new cN(null, null, array[i]);
            }
            head = n_array[0];
            //sort array
            for (int i = 0; i < n_array.Length; i++)
            {
                sortnode(head, n_array[i]);
            }
            return array_composed();

        }

        private static void sortnode(cN chead, cN node)
        {
            if (node.V > chead.V)
            {
                if (chead.R != null)
                {
                    sortnode(chead.R, node);
                }
                 else 
                {
                    chead.R = node;
                    node.L = chead;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (head == chead)
                {
                    head = node;
                    node.R = chead;
                    chead.L = node;
                }
                else
                {
                    node.R = chead;
                    node.L = chead.L;
                    chead.R = node;
                    chead.L = node;
                }
            }



        }

        private static int[] array_composed()
        {
            int[] iarr = new int[n_array.Length];
            cN chead = head;
            int counter = 0;
            while (chead != null)
            {
                iarr[counter] = chead.V;
                chead = chead.R;
                counter++;
            }
            iarr[counter] = chead.V;
            return iarr;
        }

    }
}
```

It seems like there is something wrong with my sortnode method. Its keeps recurring in an infinite loop and I can't seem to get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify question you want to convert an array of valuse into a sorted double link list , I hope I get this part right. to be honest i suggest you to change your approuch.

I suggest to first implement some importent methods like inserting a new cN into the list.
here is how i would write notearray function :

```
public static int[] notearray(int[] array)
{
      n_array = new cN[array.Length];
      for(int i=0 ; i<array.Length ; i++)
      {
          n_array[i] = insertItem(array[i]);
      }
}

private static cN insertItem(int value)
{
      cN item = new cN(null,null,value)
      int i=0;
      while(n_array[i]!=null && n_array[i].V < value)
      {
          i++;
      }

      /*
        remember to check special conditions like if this new item is going to be head or going
        to be last item in the list or both in case of empty list
      */


      item .L = n_array[i].L;
      item .R = n_array[i];
      n_array[i].L = item;

      return item;
}
```

note that n_array is not actually sorted so you must iterate like this to use them in sorted condition:

```
cn iterator = head;
for(...)
{
    doSomthing(iterator);
    iterator = iterator.R;
}
```